# Has "Killer Game Programming in Java" by Andrew Davison been rendered useless? What new tutorial should I follow?

Tags: java, 3d

Its pathetic how it was created in 2005 not so long ago when the Java 3D 1.31 API was released. Now after downloading the source code off the books website and implementing it onto my work-space it cant run. (The 3D Shooter Ch. 23) I downloaded Java 3D 1.5 API, installed it- went back to my source code and javax.media ect.., and EVERY imported class within the game simply couldn't be resolved... they are all outdated..

*Please do not say how its meant for a positive curvature in your game development skills. No ~ I got the book to understand how to code 3D textures/particle systems/games. Without seeing results how can I learn?*

If there is still hope for this book please tell me. **Otherwise what other books match this one in Game Programming?** This one was very well organized, documented and long. I am not looking for a 3D game prog. book on Java. Rather one that has the same reputation as this one but is a bit newer..

Comment: Also can I still follow the Networking Tutorial and will the Tic-Tac-Toe Game ~ work?

Comment: It's only a good resource if it's useful. Apparently it isn't useful to you. Right now your question is a bit broad. There's no correct answer to this question. It's impossible for anyone else to say if a different book would be useful to you, it's likely something you'll have to discover on your own. If there's a specific issue you're trying to solve you should ask about that instead.

Comment: @Byte56 - I am asking if there is another book as long, and reputable in any language as this. Also I am wondering if the Java 3D tutorials in the book can be made.

Comment: It's difficult to give a correct answer to that. Since the quality of the book is not quantifiable. Asking for tutorials or books on such a broad topic doesn't produce answers that are any more than opinion/suggestions. Right now, your question is a duplicate of the one linked. If you have a specific question about something you're trying to do, please ask that question.

Comment: @Byte56 - I guess http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/must-read-game-development-books would be my answer... Truth is - I am just venting right now. I was so excited when I got the book and glanced at the potential projects I would create and now I am so upset that technology moves faster than my mind....

Comment: I'm glad you found a question to satisfy. Technology does indeed move fast, 2005 is very long ago in the world of software. Good luck with your learning!