# New games ideas produce methods

Tags: game-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you come up with ideas for new games?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/how-do-you-come-up-with-ideas-for-new-games)

Hello!
I want to ask you about ideas for games, what methods do you know and which you are useing ?
I know for example method, to write a lot of smaller ideas on pieces of paper, and when I have 20-30 then, I try to connect one of them with another, to genereate new idea. For my the most difficult is to extend some idea, do you know some advice for me ?