# A methodology for creating simple sprite games (without programming technology)

Tags: game-design, sprites, flash

Do you know a manual for creating simple sprite games (without programming technology)?

The manual should contain answers to questions like "How to invent the rules", "How to create a very attractive game", "How to force a user to play constantly".

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! It sounds like you are looking for books on *game design*, as opposed to *game development* (which is more general, and will contain *game programming*). If that's the case, [search this site for game design books](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=game+design+books), and have a look at the resources mentioned in, e.g., http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/497/good-game-design-books.

Comment: "How to force a user to play constantly" - Physical restraint aside, there are lots of methods, like drugs, intimidation and/or generous use of the sorry stick. There's a more reliable way though: If the game is engaging and has a high replayability, players will return on their own. They might even enjoy it ;)  Jokes aside, Ari Feldmans book "Designing Arcade Computer Game Graphics" (available e.g. here http://wiki.yoyogames.com/index.php/Ari_Feldman%27s_Book_on_Game_Graphics)  is quite nice for the graphical aspects.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you'll find a real answer to your first two questions- "How to come up with rules" and "How to create a very attractive game" are all things that are going to change based on a lot of factors- who you're marketing to, what the goal of the game is, etc.

"How to force a user to play constantly"- I'm assuming that you're not actually meaning "force". Depending on what sort of game you're trying to build, the following articles could be of help:

http://www.video-game-addiction.org/what-makes-games-addictive.html
http://www.gamingbus.com/2011/07/27/video-game-addiction-part-two-what-makes-games-addicting/

These two articles are written purposefully vague, because the answer will depend on what you're trying to accomplish.

This is my first-ever answer, I hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 1):

[http://www.amazon.com/Game-Design-Secrets-Fourth-Edition/dp/B000IQN4M2/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1352390875&sr=8-2&keywords=Game+Design+Marc+Saltzman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000IQN4M2)

Still my favourite.

It goes into a lot of detail about how industry legends like Al Lowe design their puzzles or how the textures for Myst were made.

Definitely a great read.

Disclaimer: My opinion is based on an earlier edition from 1999. I don't know much about the newer editions.